# How can I correctly free dynamically allocated memory for a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, free

At the moment I am doing a project for school where I have to store info about some teams using a linked list which contains a number of dynamically allocated fields(a list containing data about the players, a dynamically allocated string with the teamname, their overall score etc.). The task requires that all allocated memory should be freed at the end. I am struggling toachieve this. I used the following implementation for the data structures.

```
struct player{
                 char* firstName;
                 char* secondName;
                 int score;
                 struct player* next;
              };
typedef struct player Player;
typedef struct {
                 int nr_of_members;
                 char* TeamName;
                 Player* team_members;
                 float teamscore;
             }Node_team;
struct teamlist{
                      Node_team* team;
                      struct teamlist* next;
                   };
typedef struct teamlist Teamlist;
```

All strings are dynamically allocated according to the length of the names.

For the memory liberation I tried the following idea:

```
void delete_players(Player** head)
{
    Player* p=(*head);
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        (*head)=(*head)->next;
        free(p->firstName);
        p->firstName=NULL;
        free(p->secondName);
        p->secondName=NULL;
        free(p);
        p=NULL;
        p=(*head);
    }
    (*head)=NULL;
    return;
}
void delete_list(teamlist** head)
{
    Teamlist* p=(*head);
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
          (*head)=(*head)->next;
          delete_players(&(p->team->team_members));
          free(p->team->TeamName);
          p->team->TeamName=NULL;
          free(p->team);
          p->team=NULL;
          free(p);
          p=NULL;
          p=(*head);
    }
    (*head)=NULL;
    return;
}
```

I observed that the implementation of my data structures worked for the other tasks, however when I tried to use the previous functions for freeing the memory, it crashes.
I am struggling to find the right way of freeing the memory

Edit: The list works fine before the freeing the memory, it stored all the necessary values and I can access all fields.
I have run my program through a debugger, the problem arises when I try to free the memory from a string, I have run a version where I only free the non-string fields and it doesn't crash and I do not understand why it becomes problematic when I work with the memory of the strings.
Note: the names of the data structures and fields were not written in english initially as the task required me to do so, I modified the terms to english but I may have have missed putting a capital letter somewhere, but hopefully it's not the case.
Edit2:

```
void add_player_at_end(FILE* f,Player** head)
{
    Player* newnode=(Player*)malloc(sizeof(Player)),*p;
    char buf[50];
    fscanf(f,"%s",buf);
    newnode->firstName=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(newnode->firstName,buf);
    fscanf(f,"%s",buf);
    newnode->secondName=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(newnode->secondName,buf);
    fscanf(f,"%d",&(newnode->score));
    newnode->next=NULL;
    if((*head)==NULL)
        (*head)=newnode;
    else
    {
        p=(*head);
        while((p->next)!=NULL)
            p=p->next;
        p->next=newnode;
    }
    return;
}
Node_team* createNode(FILE* f)
{
     char buf[50];
     int total=0;
     Nod_echipa* newnode=(Nod_echipa*)malloc(sizeof(Nod_echipa));
     Player* p;
     fscanf(f,"%d",&(newnode->nr_of_members));
     fgetc(f);
     fgets(buf,50,f);
     buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")]=0;
     newnode->TeamName=(char*)malloc((strlen(buf))*sizeof(char));
     if(newnode->TeamName==NULL)
        printf("alocare esuata");
     strcpy(newnode->TeamName,buf);
     newnode->team_members=NULL;
     for(int i=0;i<newnode->nr_of_members;i++)
        {
            add_player_at_end(f,&(newnode->team_members));
        }
     p=newnode->team_members;
     while(p!=NULL)
     {
         total+=p->score;
         p=p->next;
     }
     newnode->teamscore=(float)punctaj/(newnode->nr_of_members);
     return newnode;
}
void push(Teamlist** top,Node_team* Team)
{
    Teamlist* newnode=(Lista_de_echipe*)malloc(sizeof(Lista_de_echipe));
    if(newnode==NULL)
    {
        printf("alocare esuata\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    newnode->=Team;
    newnode->next=(*top);
    (*top)=newnode;
    return;
}
Teamlist* read_file(int* nr_of_teams,FILE* f)
{
    Teamlist* head=NULL;
    Node_team* Team;
    fscanf(f,"%d",nr_echipe);
    for(int i=0;i<(*nr_of_teams);i++)
    {
        Team=createNode(f);
        push(&head,Team);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return head;
}
```

This is the code I used for reading and allocating the memory, the task requires me to read from a text file that looks like this:

```
37
12 The Waiver Wire
Popa Ana-Maria 6
Popescu Alexandru 10
Pop Mihaela 6
Radu Andreea 2
Dumitru Elena 1
Stan Adrian 4
Stoica Andrei 0
Gheorghe Alexandra 6
Matei Mihai 3
Ciobanu Ionut 1
Ionescu Cristina 8
Rusu Florin 7

12 Fargo Woodchippers
Mihai Andreea-Catalina 5
Serban Marius-Mihai 3
Constantin Grigore 7
Marin Cosmin-Alexandru 4
Stefan Ionut-Florin 9
Lazar Victoria 10
Vasile Marius-Valentin 2
Munteanu Elena-Claudia 0
Ilie Maria-Roxana 10
Oprea Alina-Daniela 8
Toma Andreea-Simona 5
Florea Cristina-Daniela 0

12 Gangs of New Pork
Moldovan Erzsebet 4
Tudor Vasile-Adrian 6
Stanci Alexandru-Marius 0
Sandu Otilia 10
Ion Cristian-Mihai 3
Andrei Mihai-Catalin 10
Dinu Andra-Maria 10
Ungureanu Ioana-Mihaela 7
Anghel Alexandru-Iulian 10
Barbu Bogdan-Ioan 3
Cristea Alexandra-Georgiana 7
Ionita Cristina-Gabriela 9

12 Ferocious Killers
Neagu Nicolae-Adrian 7
Enache Cristian-Florin 8
Badea Andrei-Daniel 2
Dragomir Marius-Nicolae 10
Vlad Vladimir 7
Mocanu Marius-Bogdan 10
Grigore Mihaela-Alina 4
Voicu Bogdan-Gabriel 1
Balan Cosmina 0
Craciun Lorand 10
Ivan Claudia-Elena 4
Dobre Tamas 9

12 4Team
Iordache Valerica 7
Cojocaru Adriana-Maria 6
Muresan Cristina-Ioana 8
Lupu Elena-Diana 6
Tanase Diana-Alexandra 2
Preda Mihaela-Elena 2
Coman Ionut-Marian 7
Petre Ioana-Roxana 6
Lungu Ioan-Adrian 6
Ene Amalia 5
Manea Emilian 5
Nagy Alexandru-Stefan 7

12 Savage
Nicolae Magdalena 4
Roman Dorel 4
Dumitrescu Dumitru-Daniel 4
Simion Jozsef 3
Iancu Bogdan-Florin 6
Iacob Roxana-Andreea 9
Nistor Traian 10
Nita George-Catalin 2
Olteanu Norbert 4
Rosu Andrei-Catalin 1
Pavel Corina-Elena 0
Filip Adrian-Vasile 10

12 Pic si Poc
Bucur Marioara 9
Avram Petruta 4
Stoian Ioana-Alina 0
Rus Andrei-Bogdan 10
Dragan Alexandru-Adrian 1
Stancu Razvan-Alexandru 2
Luca Loredana-Elena 6
Calin Ionut-Cosmin 9
Diaconu Constantin-Adrian 7
David Mihai-Gabriel 1
Szabo Andrei-Mihai 4
Cretu Laura-Elena 9

12 Monster
Costea Florin-Cristian 3
Ghita Andreea-Raluca 9
Marcu Cosmin-Ionut 2
Rotaru Bogdan-Nicolae 10
Zaharia Alina-Andreea 3
Paun Mihaela-Gabriela 7
Baciu Andrada 6
Neacsu Cristina-Alexandra 8
Suciu Carmen-Elena 9
Dan Ionut-Andrei 8
Alexandru Mihai-Bogdan 9
Nedelcu Florin-Catalin 4

12 Cei 4 fantastici
Georgescu Iulia-Maria 5
Muntean Alina-Florentina 9
Costache Cristina-Andreea 5
Marinescu Ionut-Alin 9
Bogdan Ioana-Raluca 8
Vilcu Anca-Ioana 3
Ciubotariu Alexandru-Catalin 8
Demian Adrian-Constantin 7
Mustata Adrian-Ioan 5
Sanda Ramona-Maria 7
Balog Adrian-Mihai 4
Ciocoiu Alin-Constantin 7

12 ALMOST ANGELS
Neculai Denisa 7
Olah Doina 8
Baluta Maria-Alina 5
Nicu Madalina-Elena 1
Papp Elena-Georgiana 10
Badiu Elena-Raluca 7
Dina Raluca-Mihaela 8
Truta Alin-Ionut 0
Mitrache Cristian-Alexandru 6
Bercea Elena-Simona 10
Deak Marcela 8
Fazakas Virgil 9

12 ANTEATERS
Tita Cristiana 4
Frincu Mihaela-Andreea 2
Turcanu Iosif 4
Dragusin Eugenia 3
Amariei Sandor 10
Todoran Andreea-Madalina 3
Hutanu Lacramioara 5
Poenaru Mihai-Daniel 2
Trofin Izabella 10
Vizitiu Maria-Daniela 8
Mihut Natalia 10
Anghelescu Livia 5

12 AWESOME BLOSSOMS
Obreja Alina-Ioana 0
Andreescu Ionut-Marius 5
Botea Constantin-Daniel 10
Cadar Simona-Maria 6
Mihu Daniel-Ionut 10
Comanescu Delia 3
Condrea Florentin 0
Mincu Marius-Andrei 7
Muraru Emanuela 10
Ivanov Ionut-Gabriel 5
Andreica Ionut-Valentin 6
Bran Emese 9

12 FIRE ANGELS
Papuc Stelian 10
Mihali Elena-Gabriela 4
Eftimie Alina-Nicoleta 9
Stana George-Daniel 5
Macarie Maria-Andreea 3
Nastasa Cristinel 7
Dragnea Bogdan-Mihai 2
Margarit Andreea-Gabriela 8
Pirvan Emoke 7
Tomoiaga Andreea-Daniela 4
Craciunescu Angelica 9
Negrila Anca-Mihaela 4

12 FIRE CRACKER
Mate Florin-Alexandru 5
Cimpean Ionica 1
Szakacs Manuela 7
Tiron Constantin-Catalin 4
Ciornei Felicia 10
Fekete Marina 6
Mutu George-Adrian 8
Ferencz Vlad-Alexandru 8
Cimpeanu Mioara 0
Neag Florin-Daniel 7
Butnariu Florin-Adrian 3
Mihaescu Daniela-Elena 9

12 FLAMES
Velicu Gina 0
Panaite Adrian-Nicolae 1
Avramescu Bogdan-Constantin 5
Denes Noemi 8
Petrut Mihai-Andrei 4
Oana Elena-Ramona 0
Bordea Alina-Gabriela 6
Cruceru Razvan-Ionut 4
Rotar Oana-Cristina 2
Mardare Alexandra-Cristina 2
Miklos Raluca-Ioana 9
Barna Eduard 6

12 FUGITIVES
Tudoran Bogdan-Andrei 7
Traistaru Alexandru-Ioan 9
Borza Monika 1
Cernea Ruxandra 3
Vacaru Constantin-Cosmin 3
Bala Mihai-Cristian 8
Maria Adrian-Florin 8
Onica Dan-Alexandru 8
Manescu Marius-Constantin 9
Pruna Eva 4
Gavrilescu Andrei-Cristian 0
Ambrus Tatiana 8

12 MANTIS
Lixandru Alexandru-Florin 8
Jipa Alexandru-Nicolae 8
Lup Mihai-Adrian 4
Loghin Ildiko 6
Gliga Madalin 4
Valeanu Cristian-Ionut 7
Balas Alexandru-Bogdan 4
Bartha Oana-Mihaela 2
Stoicescu George-Cristian 9
Vilceanu Reka 7
Stuparu Larisa 10
Bordeianu Orsolya 2

12 MENEHUNES
Iosub Calin 6
Goia Alexandru-Marian 3
Lacatusu Florica 4
Danci Marius-Gabriel 8
Pascal Zsuzsanna 6
Antonescu Marius-Florin 1
Buruiana Dana 1
Jakab Alexandra-Mihaela 0
Fabian Alexandru-Constantin 10
Gherghina Aurelian 0
Virlan Beata 4
Bulai Andreea-Nicoleta 0

12 MIGHTY GRASSHOPPERS
Cristache Costin 8
Lepadatu Geanina 10
Ureche Maria-Mirabela 7
Nicolau Adela 7
Doroftei Marcel 1
Joita Petre 7
Kadar Csilla 2
Abrudan Elisabeta 9
Androne Maria-Mihaela 2
Gruia Marius-Alexandru 6
Vladescu Annamaria 2
Stoican Roxana-Mihaela 4

12 MILLENNIUM JUMPERS
Costan Ramona-Elena 1
Gherghel Tiberiu 5
Paul Gheorghita 7
Urs Marin 8
Goga Catalin-Ionut 10
Tabacaru Andreea-Roxana 4
Zamfirescu Alina-Cristina 8
Botez Tunde 3
Jitaru Teodor 6
Bora Mihaela-Cristina 2
Aron Sorina 1
Badulescu Elena-Loredana 10

12 MUTINY
Tugui Ionut-Bogdan 3
Nanu George-Alexandru 0
Raduta Simona-Elena 10
Pirvulescu Alexandru-Gabriel 0
Olar Ioan-Alexandru 1
Ioana Alina-Georgiana 1
Vancea Oana-Alexandra 1
Minca Lidia 7
Benedek Maria-Madalina 0
Sasu Raluca-Maria 8
Eremia Emanuel 3
Ursachi Oana-Elena 1

12 SCREAMING EAGLES
Chereches Lenuta 2
Condurache Marilena 4
Curca Alexandru-Daniel 8
Coca Szabolcs 4
Dunca Ecaterina 10
Ababei Andrei-Ionut 9
Mezei Adelina 8
Lita Oana-Andreea 9
Voda Kinga 3
Mogos Anisoara 2
Cioara Marius-Daniel 6
Stinga Andreea-Alexandra 0

12 SHOCKWAVE
Corbu Ionut-Adrian 5
Nichita Ionut-Cristian 2
Pascalau Marius-Adrian 4
Voiculescu Andrei-Alexandru 0
Gutu Mihaita 4
Ancuta Elena-Madalina 3
Muscalu Marius-Catalin 8
Carstea Cristina-Mihaela 5
Hanganu Ioana-Andreea 3
Dita Andreea-Georgiana 7
Buzea Adrian-Ionut 5
Safta Elena-Mihaela 2

12 SILVER SHARKS
Purice Alexandru-Mihai 9
Taranu Andreea-Ioana 4
Chelariu Erika 10
Nicolaescu Dorin 7
Covrig Angela 1
Iftime Emil 0
Tudorica Georgian 9
Burtea Elena-Roxana 1
Marchis Dorina 4
Danaila Marius-Cristian 4
Juganaru Elena-Alexandra 5
Fieraru Diana-Elena 4

12 SLAMMER
Bordei Florian 2
Ciorba Eniko 1
Hategan Diana-Maria 0
Porumb Raluca-Elena 3
Surugiu Ionut-Catalin 1
Csiki Melinda 7
Amza Mihail 4
Vicol Anca-Elena 6
Prisacariu Petrica 9
Capraru Alexandru-Cristian 6
Zidaru Laszlo 4
Vornicu Ioana-Cristina 0

12 SNOW DEVILS
Cismaru Alexandra-Elena 9
Laza Aurel 1
Iovan Bogdan-Alexandru 5
Creanga Andra 1
Dinica Bianca 7
Balasoiu Alexandra-Ioana 8
Agache Petronela 2
Din Marius-Ionut 3
Chelu Paula 2
Mot Katalin 1
Balaceanu Ionut-Daniel 10
Mihaly Nicusor 1

12 SOCCER SISTERS
Enciu Octavian 1
Gorgan Cornel 6
Blanaru Tudor 1
Stratulat Andrea 6
Tinca Roxana-Maria 0
Ceausu Csaba 4
Bursuc Danut 8
Dragne Bogdan-Ionut 0
Suteu Elena-Daniela 5
Varzaru Stefania 8
Dumitras Sebastian 2
Vesa Aurelia 5

12 SPARKS
Calugaru Andreea-Mihaela 2
Furtuna Teodora 4
Postelnicu Elena-Alina 9
Burciu Eugen 9
Mathe Luminita 10
Nutu Cornelia 3
Stef Maria-Magdalena 9
Stroie Maria-Alexandra 8
Lung Levente 2
Cuc Lavinia 1
Giurca Elena-Andreea 7
Manaila Ilie 7

12 SPRINTERS
Nacu Ancuta 8
Cocos Alexandru-Ionut 9
Gaman Viorica 10
Manu Sergiu 8
Benea Ionut-Alexandru 8
Lazea Zsolt 8
Graur Ioana-Maria 7
Badita Andreea-Cristina 10
Stanculescu Emilia 3
Oprisan Timea 8
Rata Mihai-Alexandru 3
Leca Istvan 1

12 STING RAYS
Trasca Ileana 2
Brasoveanu Silvia 0
Ionel Veronica 2
Borcan Marinela 5
Mihoc Cristina-Maria 6
Manciu Rodica 4
Bruma Anca-Maria 10
Ticu Violeta 7
Murgu Roxana-Elena 8
Miclaus Zoltan 9
Tanko Alexandra-Maria 5
Brinza Ioana-Alexandra 5

12 SUGER BEES
Grigoriu Alina-Maria 10
Tutuianu Dragos 2
Kerekes Silviu 2
Santa Andreea-Maria 10
Kocsis Adina 1
Salagean Attila 7
Voinescu Liviu 7
Butoi Petru 9
Leahu Cristina-Elena 6
Pauna Vasilica 4
Dobrica Victor 6
Gurau Alina-Mihaela 1

12 SUPER SONIC SOCCERS
Bot Oana-Maria 1
Balla Camelia 1
Maciuca Andreea-Elena 0
Bejenaru Dan 5
Zota Costel 9
Balta Alina-Elena 1
Vieriu Elena-Cristina 6
Ciortan Mircea 0
Irimescu Laurentiu 10
Velea Georgeta 6
Pricope Maria-Cristina 6
Coste Paul 6

12 TANGERINES
Nitulescu Radu 8
Vrinceanu Liliana 3
Mitrofan Valentina 2
Jurj Viorel 3
Vladut Iulia 10
Ciocirlan Ovidiu 5
Tuca Florina 8
Chirea Robert 9
Balaci Catalina 7
Dediu Carmen 8
Floarea Claudiu 7
Dulgheru Alin 7

12 TEAM USA
Platon Sorin 5
Plesca Loredana 3
Bucsa Claudia 5
Borcea Monica 9
Podaru Ramona 5
Pascariu Dumitru 10
Glavan Ana 10
Ana Ciprian 7
Scutaru Corina 0
Belu Laura 9
Angheluta Vlad 10
Catrina Razvan 9

12 TIGERS
Ivanescu Iulian 10
Badila Roxana 3
Prisecaru Oana 8
Moroianu Irina 10
Geana Diana 10
Furdui Mirela 1
Chirca Iuliana 3
Motoc Madalina 7
Datcu Raluca 2
Burghelea Ionel 3
Leu Lucian 0
Galan Cosmin 2

12 TOUCANS
Mladin George 8
Pascaru Ioan 6
Lupsa Valentin 0
Luta Adriana 3
Vass Ionela 4
Oniga Catalin 7
Mates Stefan 10
Deliu Ion 9
Angelescu Florentina 8
Hagiu Anca 2
Codrea Anamaria 5
Fechete Simona 3

12 TYPHOONS
Dedu Maria 1
Druga Ioana 4
Florian Constantin 8
Ungurean Nicoleta 10
Mitrica Georgiana 0
Iftimie Mariana 7
Biris Bogdan 7
Vranceanu Vasile 0
Cirjan Gabriel 10
Buzdugan Gabriela 4
Cobzaru Nicolae 8
Manda Gheorghe 7

12 VIOLET VIPERS
Vincze Andrei 3
Bulgaru Alexandra 0
Grigorie Mihai 2
Placinta Ionut 5
Antonie Cristina 3
Ciuperca Florin 0
Popa Daniel 7
Popescu Marian 9
Pop Marius 6
Radu Cristian 6
Dumitru Daniela 1
Stan Alina 10
```

Comment: You can make your problem easier by not doing this much at once - `delete_players` should call `delete_player` so you don't have to juggle name-deallocation and node-deallocation in the same space.

Comment: Are you sure you linked the nodes correctly (and the last one's *next* points to *NULL*)?

Comment: You should run your program in a debugger. It should tell you where is crashes. Then you can inspect the variables involved in the statement. You access lots of pointers without checking if it is a `NULL` pointer: `&(p->team->team_members));` What if `p->team` is holding `NULL`?

Comment: As a general rule, memory should be freed in the opposite order it was allocated. There should be a kind of symmetry: allocate A, B, C ... deallocate C, B, A. So, look at how memory is allocated and make sure that each allocation has a symmetric deallocation.

Comment: Sidenote: It does not make any sense to assign `NULL` to a pointer inside a struct if you free the whole struct right afterwards or if you assign another value right in the next line. That just makes the code less readable.

Comment: Regarding your edit: That still does not explain how you allocate your memory for the list. Please show a minimal example that we can compile and that reproduces the error.

Comment: Just a blind guess because you still do not show the requested code: Do you assign string literals to your pointers or do you allocate memory for all of your strings?

Comment: Your code does not match the data data structure definitions provided.  You define a `struct teamlist` and a `Teamlist`, but the code refers to `teamlist`, which does not match either.  C++ would be ok with that, but the question is tagged C, and in any case, if you were using C++ then it would be better to do without the typedefs altogether.  So present real code, in the form of a [mre], else it will be very hard for us to help you.

Comment: More generally, the data structures are a messy hodge-podge.  Players are linked-list nodes themselves, but teams have separate data structures and linked-list nodes.  Naming conventions are inconsistent.  And mixing in typedefs with that makes it worse, not better.

Comment: Even with all that, however, I don't see anything fundamentally wrong with the deallocation functions presented.  If your program is crashing, it is presumably because they are making (plausible) assumptions about that data to be freed that the rest of the program is failing to satisfy.

Comment: `newnode->TeamName=(char*)malloc((strlen(buf))*sizeof(char));` You forgot to allocate memory for the terminating 0 byte. Reading from that string will cause out of bountds accesses which invoke undefined behaviour. Also: You do not need and also should not cast the result of `malloc` as this can hide errors. Using `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. You don't need to multiple it here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253660/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-john-bollinger).

Comment: I would argue those destructor null pointer immediate assignments indicating you've freed memory might be good practice. (In that you've created a sequence-point where the program is in a valid state between the calls to `free`; at least this might be good for debugging.)

Comment: Its good time to also learn about structure's member packing and alignment.